# How do I delete a CloudFormation Stack that has Exports in use?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have created a CloudFormation stack that had an export.  I was originally going to split this stack into multiple nested stacks, and the export was required.  It is no longer required as I have come to a much more elegant design.

When I tried to delete the original stack, I got UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED because it told me the export was in use.

My workaround has been to rename the stack 'stack2' and continued on.

But it's very annoying that my original stack name is stuck.

Short of paying for AWS support, is there any way to force a delete of this stack?

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the other stack that is using the export first, or update the other stack to not use the export.